# R/gtsummary: Exclude some p-values and change the footnote

Tags: r, gtsummary

Does anyone know if it is possible exclude some p-values from the a summary table (`tbl_summary()` with `add_p()`)?

Also, can we change the footnote about the tests used?

```r
library(gtsummary)

mtcars %>%
tbl_summary(by = am) %>%
add_p()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are great customization questions and the answers are YES!!

First of all, you can use the `include =` argument to the `add_p()` function, with a character vector of variables you want to include (or exclude using `-`), or any [tidyselect helper](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/select_helpers.html) (i.e. `starts_with()`), to select which p-values to include in the table.

Next, I've provided an example using the arguments from {gt} package on how to modify the default footnote listing tests. Another example can be seen in the [{gtsummary} gallery of tables](http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/gallery.html).

Good luck, hope this helps!

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
library(gt)

trial %>% 
  select(trt, stage, age, grade) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>% 
  add_p(
    include = c(-age) #Can use any tidyselect helpers/select syntax to specify which p-vals
  ) %>% 
  as_gt(include = -tab_footnote) %>%  # if using gt, can exclude footnotes this way 
  tab_footnote( # and can modify/add footnotes this way
    footnote = "Tests used are...",
    locations = cells_column_labels(columns = vars(p.value))
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An other way is to directly tweek the list:

```
plouf <- mtcars %>%
  tbl_summary(by = am) %>%
  add_p()
plouf$table_body[1,"p.value"] <- NA
plouf$table_header[6,"footnote"] <- "my personal statistic test"
plouf
```

[image]